# How to implement activitity indicator for maps on clicking the alert view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, activity-indicator

I am new to iphone development.I am creating a map application.I want to display the activity indicator rotating when i click ok for the alert view "Do you want to load the current location". Since this alert is given  default by ipod how can i give activity indicator for it? Please help me out.Please guide me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the delegate for your `UIAlertView`, the `UIAlertViewDelegate`, you can make a call like this to make the activity indicator start spinning:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible: YES];
```

Then when you are done loading, stop the activity indicator with the same call.